# Convert a list to dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops, python-itertools

```
from itertools import chain
data_c = chain(data[0].values,
data[1].values,
data[2].values,
data[3].values,
data[4].values,
data[5].values,
data[6].values)

headers=chain(data[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(data_c, columns=headers)
```

I have used the above code lines to convert a list to a pd dataframe and it works fine. The result looks like this.[all 178 rows displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxAPs.png)

However, i want to loop through all the list data so I have used the following codes:

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd
for i in range (0, len(data)):
    data_c = chain(data[i].values)

headers=chain(data[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(data_c,columns=headers)
```

The result only shows the last value (which is the data[6].values).[Only 8 rows are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itf44.png)
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: What's in `data`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I have added the images for clarity.

Comment: I mean, what are the objects in `data`? I'm thinking, if they're Pandas objects, this could be way easier.

Comment: BTW, avoid `for i in range(len())`. Instead do `for x in data: ... chain(x.values)`. If you needed the indexes, you could use `enumerate()`.

Comment: This code looks like you are trying to transpose a Dataframe called `data` to `df` (ie. swapping rows to columns and columns to rows) - is that right?  If so then remove the for loop and replace with `data_c = it.chain(data[i].values for i in range(len(data.columns)))`.  or you could just use the pd.transpose function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range (0, len(data)):
    data_c = chain(data[i].values)
    # Here every time loop runs data_c values override to a new chain object, That's why the data_c value in set to the last value.
```

Try this.

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

data_c = chain(*[ele.values for ele in data]) 

headers=chain(data[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(data_c,columns=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to append data in the loop for every iteration of data;

```
data_c = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (0, len(data)):
    data_c = pd.concat[data_c,chain(data[i].values)]
```